# How to install new linux OS in place of old one if old one had / and /boot partitions while dual booted with Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I've got dual boot with Windows and I'm wondering how to install and replace the Linux OS if it has `/boot/efi` for Windows and Linux and `/` partition.

I need to use `blivet` GUI and it's Fedora 34 (I have to use that version, the reason is too complicated for this post).

Preferably I'd like to save all my stuff on both Linux and Windows but if that's impossible it's still ok.

Comment: 1. Do not confuse mount points with partitions; 2. You can reuse partitions or start from scratch **as long as you don'¡t delete the ESP (EFI System Partition).** So yes, you must know what you're doing.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So i don't touch anything with `/boot/efi` partition? What would i need to do if i wanted to save my data and install Fedora?

Comment: That's the mount point I mentioned in #1